# html5 video, media player details on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I am very new to programming. Trying to build a nice webpage with a custom media player. I have a box below the player which has an overflow scroll and when you click the each video it plays as it is supposed to...but i am having issues trying to get an info box on the top right to display when each separate video is clicked.  For example:

myvideo.mp4...you click

```
----------------------
|                     |                  Header                               Date of video
|                     |
|                     |           <p> with info on video
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
-----------------------       
                         Below is the list of video's in a box with overflow-y:scroll
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

check it out....its a popup window just so you know.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99737964/video%20online/sermonvideos.html

right click for page source to view my code.

I am only a couple of weeks in from learning anything about web development,design,programming.  I'm 27 and just recently found out how much I enjoy learning about this.  I appreciate the advice and help.  Thanks!

Comment: hahaha...thank Raptor...it looks much better like that..lol